# How to add image into Angular Material table column?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using an Angular Material table. I wanted to have an icon before the flag text in that column, or how do I add a column with icons? for some reason I can't see how this can be done. My code so far is:

component.ts

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  date: string;
  action: string;
  mileage: string;
  author: string;
  flag: string;
}

  const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late"},
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late"},
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late"},
];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['date', 'action', 'mileage', 'author', 'flag'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
```

HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="flag">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Flag</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="status">{{element.flag}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as simple as adding an additional property to your data model, e.g. `icon`:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  date: string;
  action: string;
  mileage: string;
  author: string;
  flag: string;
  icon: string;
}
```

Setting the property to whatever icon you want (check icons [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/)):

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late", icon: "flight_land"},
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late", icon: "flight_land"},
  {date: 'xxxxx', action: 'xxxxx', mileage: "xxxxx", author:"xxxxx", flag:"Late", icon: "flight_land"},
];
```

And then using it in your Flag column:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="status"><mat-icon>{{element.icon}}</mat-icon>{{element.flag}}</td>
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-xb82r2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a simple stackblitz based on the Angular Material table example
>   with an icon displayed based on the property `icon` defined on the
>   table data.